# How do I choose the icon for a place that I add to a Google Map (in My Places) when I add it?

Tags: google-maps

This is the way it seems like I have to add places to a map I've made in "My Places":

1. Open map
2. Search for the place I want to add
3. Click on its icon on the map, or on the left in its entry
4. Click "save to map" in its bubble, select the map I want to save to, and click the save button

It now has the icon/marker type of the *previous* place I saved.  So if the last place was a hotel, but I just added a restaurant, this restaurant has a bed icon from the old hotel.  So now,

1. Click "view map" on the thing that popped up on the top that says "[place name] was saved to [map name]" (or click on My Places and find my map again)
2. Click the red edit button
3. Find the place that I just saved in the list of places on this map on the left (always the last item, I guess) and click it
4. On the bubble that pops up, click the icon in the upper right
5. Choose the icon I want for this place

Am I doing something wrong?  It seems bizarre that when I add a place, I have to go through all these extra steps to choose the icon that I want for it.  Is there a way to choose the icon when I add it to the map?

Or at least is there a way to add places (with the correct icon) that's easier than what I described above?

Comment: If you want to use the Google Maps interface in order to change the icon then, yes, you really do have to go through those steps (as opposed to if you were adding places/icons via the API or something to that effect).

Comment: Just a details: you have to login with your google account to add the place in a map